# Apple sign in not working after deploying to TestFlight

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, flutter, testflight

I have Sign in with Apple enabled in my application. After implementing it, it works fine when i run the app from Xcode. However, when i deployed the App to TestFlight, nothing seems to happen when i click the button. Is there anything that I should change from development to production before posting to TestFlight. All the other social logins are working fine, like Google and Facebook.

Thanks,

Comment: did you find any solution for this ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable "Sign in with Apple" for production in Xcode.

Navigate to the App > Signing & Capabilities > Select "Release" tab > click + and find "Sign in with Apple".

It should look like this (Xcode 13.4.1):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you already have access to sign in with apple.
Please go Settings > Click on your apple id[First option] > Password & Security > Apps using Apple ID.
You'll find your app over there. Remove it and try again. It'll work.

Whenever user sign with apple, you need to save his info in either keychain. when user is authenticated 2nd time you won't get all user info.
You need to retrieve this info from keychain.
One more thing, make sure that user sees the alert when his data is not available, otherwise Apple will reject the app due to Unable to sign in.
Use this code, made changes according to your requirement.

```
// MARK: - Apple Sign In Delegate
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
extension SignupVC: ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate {
    func setupAppleButton() {
        var btnAuthorization = ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton(type: .signIn, style: .black)
        if #available(iOS 13.2, *) {
            btnAuthorization = ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton(type: .signUp, style: .black)
        }
        btnAuthorization.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 14, width: view.frame.size.width - 32, height: 44)
        btnAuthorization.addTarget(self, action: #selector(appleLogin), for: .touchUpInside)
        viewApple.addSubview(btnAuthorization)
    }
    @objc func appleLogin() {
        let appleIDProvider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()
        let request = appleIDProvider.createRequest()
        request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]

        let authorizationController = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [request])
        authorizationController.delegate = self
        authorizationController.presentationContextProvider = self
        authorizationController.performRequests()
    }
    /// Prepare requests for both Apple ID and password providers.
    private func performExistingAccountSetupFlows() {
        let requests = [ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider().createRequest(), ASAuthorizationPasswordProvider().createRequest()]
        
        // Create an authorization controller with the given requests.
        let authorizationController = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: requests)
        authorizationController.delegate = self
        authorizationController.presentationContextProvider = self
        authorizationController.performRequests()
    }

    /// ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate function for authorization failed
    func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithError error: Error) {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    /// ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate function for successful authorization
    func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization) {
        if let appleIDCredential = authorization.credential as? ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential {
            // Create an account as per your requirement
            let appleUserFirstName = appleIDCredential.fullName?.givenName
            let appleUserLastName = appleIDCredential.fullName?.familyName
            let appleUserEmail = appleIDCredential.email
            
            guard [appleUserFirstName, appleUserLastName, appleUserEmail].contains(nil) else {
                keyChainHelper.appleUserID = appleIDCredential.user
                keyChainHelper.appleUserFname = appleUserFirstName
                keyChainHelper.appleUserLname = appleUserLastName
                keyChainHelper.appleUserEmail = appleUserEmail
                // Continue to your work
                return
            }
            let appleIDProvider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()
            appleIDProvider.getCredentialState(forUserID: appleIDCredential.user) { (credentialState, _) in
                switch credentialState {
                case .authorized:
                    guard let userID = self.keyChainHelper.appleUserID else {
                        print("data is not available.")
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.showAlertToReset()
                        }
                        return }
                    if userID == appleIDCredential.user {
                        // Credential is valid
                        // Continiue to show 'User's Profile' Screen
                        
                        //Get saved info from Keychain
                        // Continue to your work
                        //self.keyChainHelper.appleUserFname, lName: self.keyChainHelper.appleUserLname, email: self.keyChainHelper.appleUserEmail)
                    }
                case .revoked:
                    // Credential is revoked.
                    // Show 'Sign In' Screen
                    break
                case .notFound:
                    // Credential not found.
                    // Show 'Sign In' Screen
                    break
                default:
                    break
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
    func showAlertToReset() {
        let alert = ADDAlertController(title: "", message:"Please reset account permission from Password & Security to Sign up with Apple.\nTap Settings > [your name] > Password & Security > Apple ID logins\n\nSwipe left on your app, tap delete > Stop using.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: strings.ok().uppercased(), style: .default, handler: nil))
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
extension SignupVC: ASAuthorizationControllerPresentationContextProviding {
    // For present window
    func presentationAnchor(for controller: ASAuthorizationController) -> ASPresentationAnchor {
        return view.window!
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right, i checked and it was in apps using apple ID. But, it still is not working. I made a few changes to the code and published a new version. Let's see if that helps.

Comment: No need to upload on test flight. Remove it from apps using apple ID.
install again. When you get user name and email save it to keychain.
Delete app & install again.
If you are signing 2nd time you'll get credentialState authorised.
If data is available continue to your work of show alert to remove.
It'll work properly

Comment: @ahmadnoori did you find any solution for this ? I'm also stuck on this problem

Comment: @HanzalaRaza make sure you have activated apple_sign in production environment, not only in debug in Xcode

Comment: how to do this ?